# Delayed execution using epoll main loop

Tags: c, asynchronous, epoll

How would I create a delayed execution of code or timeout events using `epoll`? Both libevent and libev has the functionality but I can't figure out how to do this using epoll.

Currently the main loop looks like this:

```
epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, client_sock_fd, &epev);

while(1) {
    int nfds = epoll_wait(epfd, &epev, 1, 10);
    if (nfds < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (nfds > 0) {
        // If an event has been recieved
    }
    // Do this every 10ms
}
```

I am well aware that this functionality could  be achieved by simply adding how much time has passed but using epoll seems like a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [timerfd](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) and add the file descriptor to the epoll_wait

Answer (score -1):

Stupid question: why not just keep track of the time explicitly?  I do this in a multi-TCP client (for sending heartbeats) and the loop essentially does:

```
uint64_t last = get_time_in_usec();
uint64_t event_interval = 10 * 1000;
while(1) {
    int nfds = epoll_wait(epfd, &epev, 1, 0); /* note that i set timeout = 0 */
    if (nfds <= 0) { /* do some cleanup logic, handle EAGAIN */
    if (nfds > 0) { /* If an event has been received */ }
    if(get_time_in_usec() >= last + event_interval) { ... }
}
```

`get_time_in_usec` can be implemented using `gettimeofday` or `rdtsc` in linux.  YMMV

Comment: As I wrote I just wanted a cleaner epoll way of doing it, but yes, this is the other way of doing it as I see it. Will accept this answer if no other is posted within a reasonable time.

Comment: This approach will load the cpu at 100% for no good reason. You should not spin when you want to sleep.

Comment: "You should not spin when you want to sleep" You should spin when response time is important (you have no guarantee when you get back from a sleep, and you incur system calls -- there are special NICs which reduce epoll operations to userspace, effectively allowing you to run without risking a kernel entry)

Comment: Agree, no point to wake up when there is nothing to do. epoll timeout should be the duration till the earliest timer or -1 if no timers.